# How to generate a Download link in php from a VarBinary in SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server

i have the following problem, i have this varBinary that was inserted in this way

```
INSERT INTO [Valpo-SIG] SELECT 4, 'Limite Comunal', bulkcolumn FROM OPENROWSET( BULK 'C:\Users\daniel.rodriguez\Documents\Unidad Vecinal.kmz', SINGLE_BLOB ) AS y
```

and the end result looks like this

[image: End Result of Table]

The thing is that i have managed to create an usable .KMZ file using the following code

```
    DECLARE @SQLIMG VARBINARY(MAX),
@DOC_PATH VARCHAR(50) = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\Practica1\tmp\'  ,
@TIMESTAMP VARCHAR(MAX),
@ObjectToken INT,
@FILENAME VARCHAR(50) = 'NewFilea.kmz',
@TOTALPATH VARCHAR(100) 

SET @TOTALPATH = @DOC_PATH + @FILENAME

SELECT @SQLIMG = Plano from [Valpo-SIG] where [Id-SIG] = 2

    --PRINT @TIMESTAMP
    --PRINT @SQLIMG

    EXEC sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream', @ObjectToken OUTPUT
    EXEC sp_OASetProperty @ObjectToken, 'Type', 1
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Open'
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Write', NULL, @SQLIMG  --new variable here
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'SaveToFile', NULL, @TOTALPATH, 2
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Close'
    EXEC sp_OADestroy @ObjectToken
```

the code above creates a file named NewFilea.kmz with the information Stored on Plano inside the [Valpo-SIG] table.

Then i placed the Query inside a PHP variable

```
        $sql ="DECLARE @SQLIMG VARBINARY(MAX),
@DOC_PATH VARCHAR(50) = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\Practica1\tmp\'  ,
@TIMESTAMP VARCHAR(MAX),
@ObjectToken INT,
@FILENAME VARCHAR(50) = 'NewFilea.kmz',
@TOTALPATH VARCHAR(100) 

SET @TOTALPATH = @DOC_PATH + @FILENAME

SELECT @SQLIMG = Plano from [Valpo-SIG] where [Id-SIG] = 2

    --PRINT @TIMESTAMP
    --PRINT @SQLIMG

    EXEC sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream', @ObjectToken OUTPUT
    EXEC sp_OASetProperty @ObjectToken, 'Type', 1
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Open'
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Write', NULL, @SQLIMG  --new variable here
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'SaveToFile', NULL, @TOTALPATH, 2
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Close'
    EXEC sp_OADestroy @ObjectToken";
```

and after that i use the Microsoft sql Server drivers to Try to use that sql

```
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql, array(), array("Scrollable" =>  'static')) or die('Error, query failed');
```

But it fails, and i don't know any other way of creating  a file from a SQL Server database, almost all the documentation is either for retrieving Blobs (which that's the way i inserted it inside the Database i believe) from MySQL OR just explaining the process for creating the file FROM the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio which defeats the purpose of storing the file inside the DB in the first place

Im using SQL Server 2017 Developer Edition and PHP 7.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after trying to find an answer to my own question, the only solution that could somewhat fix my problem was to Create a Procedure in the database. For example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CreateArchive
(
  @idplan int,
  @FILENAME VARCHAR(50)
)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @SQLIMG VARBINARY(MAX),
@DOC_PATH VARCHAR(50) = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\Practica1\tmp\'  ,
@TIMESTAMP VARCHAR(MAX),
@ObjectToken INT,
@TOTALPATH VARCHAR(100) 

SET @TOTALPATH = @DOC_PATH + @FILENAME + '.kmz'

SELECT @SQLIMG = Plano from [Valpo-SIG] where [Id-SIG] = @idplan

    --PRINT @TIMESTAMP
    --PRINT @SQLIMG

    EXEC sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream', @ObjectToken OUTPUT
    EXEC sp_OASetProperty @ObjectToken, 'Type', 1
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Open'
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Write', NULL, @SQLIMG  --new variable here
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'SaveToFile', NULL, @TOTALPATH, 2
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Close'
    EXEC sp_OADestroy @ObjectToken
END
GO
```

Both @idplan and @FILENAME are variables that you must supply when you call the procedure, the first one is the ID of the query and @FILENAME is the name the file will have, @SQLIMG is where the field value that makes the archive while @Doc_Path is the path where the file will be created, @TotalPath is the complete name, combining @Doc_Path and @Filename, the '.kmz' is because of an oversight on my own fault but is easily fixed, ill explain in a moment.

After the Procedure is stored in the Database, in php you have to do 2 things
First you have to prepare the Special query, with the command sqlsrv_prepare($conn,$sql) because if you try to do the normal sqlsrv_query, it will return an error, also you need to assign the value of the variables that will be used in the procedure if it applies

```
header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");
$serverName = "(local)"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array("Database" => "mulet", "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8",'ReturnDatesAsStrings' => true);//DB
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);//Connection is generated
$number = 3;
$name = "Example";
$sql =" Execute CreateArchive $number,$name";
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn,$sql);
```

and after that you have to use the sqlsrv command sqlserver_execute to properly execute the procedure, for example

```
if (!sqlsrv_execute($stmt)) 
{
echo "Your code is fail!";
die;
}
```

this will create a file in the folder C:\xampp\htdocs\Practica1\tmp\, So hope this answer helps anyone that happens to find my same trouble, and excuse my weird english, my main language is spanish

Have a nice Day